# Executing nested loops+foreach+csh

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, nested

It's been a while since I used csh formatting and I am having a little bit of trouble with a few things. Things seem so much easier to execute in Matlab, however I need to do this on the terminal because of the programs I am trying to interact with.

So here's what I want to do: I have a file del.txt that is structured like this

1

2

3

4

etc. So each value is in it's own row and there's one column for all the data. I have a bunch of other files that are within my directory. I want to match up say value 1 (which in this case is 1) with file 1 and value 2 with file 2, etc and so on and so forth. So here's what I did...

Code:

## !/bin/csh

foreach a (`cat del.txt`)

foreach sta(`ls *.HHZ`)

```
echo a is $a

echo $sta


cat <<END>>macro.m
```

r $a

r $sta

END

```
sac macro.m

rm macro.m
```

end

end

However what I achieve is that it loops through all of the values in del.txt and each file and then moves on to the next file within my directory and loops through all of the values. I'm having trouble figuring out the format that this should be in to match up the correct values. I'm not doing much within the script yet until I can get them to match up. Please help Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I read that the foreach command will execute all the commands on each file..but haven't been able to find a way to get around this. What I want it to do is take value 1 from del.txt and match it up with file 1 (sta) from the directory finish the loop, then take value 2 from del.txt and match it up with file 2 from the directory (sta). I've never done more than just simple iterations with csh on one subset of files, and I am not sure how to reference the values to one another. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I haven't found a simple way to do this without writing everything out. I looked at the 'for' and 'while' commands..if there is a simple way to do it I'm not seeing it.

Cheers,
K

Answer (score 0):

IF I am understanding correctly, You have a txt file will list of strings and you want it to match with the files.

I am assuming by this particular statement of yours:

> I want to match up say value 1 (which in this case is 1) with file 1

You mean to match the string at 1 with file name of file 1.

Here's a possible solution based on this assumption(this will help you anyway with loop):

```
#Store value in file.txt in a array
set file_var = `cat file.txt`
#Store file list in my_dir in a var
set my_dir = <your dir path>
set file_list_var = `ls $my_dir`

#Let's print "file Match: for every match
foreach var1 ($file_var)
     foreach var2 ($file_list_var)
          if("$var1" == "$var2") echo $var1 = $var2 : Match Found.
     endif
endif
```